# Object.constructor and Function both command returns function Function() in the console (firefox) please explain what is happening?

Tags: javascript

> *if we write Object.constructor and Function  in the browser console both return function Function() . why? For example Object.constructor === Function return true*

```js
console.log(Object.constructor);
console.log(Function);
```

*

Comment: Because `Object.constructor` is `Function`.

Comment: Because `Object` is a built in function whose prototype is `Function.prototype`. Therefore `Object.constructor == Function.prototype.constructor == Function`. Reference: https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/#sec-properties-of-the-object-constructor, https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/#sec-function.prototype.constructor